# MongoDB createIndexes exception on MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.Delete

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using *C# MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.10.1.73*.

Note I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218966/creating-mongodb-unique-key-with-c-sharp), not my issue whatsoever.

Error message:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteConcernException: Command 'createIndexes'
>   failed: exception: Index with name: filename_1_uploadDate_1 already
>   exists with different options (response: {
>   "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false, "numIndexesBefore" : 4,
>   "errmsg" : "exception: Index with name: filename_1_uploadDate_1
>   already exists with different options", "code" : 85, "ok" : 0.0 })

```
MongoDatabase _database;
var query = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.And(
    MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(ColumnFilename, filePath),
    MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(ColumnWidth, width),
    MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(ColumnHeight, height));

var mongoFileInfo = _database.GridFS.FindOne(query);
if (mongoFileInfo != null) { 
    var mongoStream = mongoFileInfo.OpenRead();
    if (/*some condition*/) {
        mongoStream.Close();
        mongoStream.Dispose();
        mongoFileInfo.Delete(); // exception here
    }
```

Full stack trace:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.CreateIndex(IMongoIndexKeys keys,
>   IMongoIndexOptions options)
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.CreateIndex(IMongoIndexKeys keys)
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.CreateIndex(String[] keyNames)
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFS.EnsureIndexes(Int32 maxFiles)
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFS.EnsureIndexes()
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.Delete()

Comment: I don't see how this error is related to this code. Which line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: Both stack trace and line throwing exception are marked in the question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filename_1_uploadDate_1` index is created by default on my Mongo server version 3.0.7. Default setting for unique is *'not unique'*. Whenever some piece of code was forcing this index to be unique(as I think it should), aforementioned exception occurred on deleting from Mongo.

Resolution: if index not present create it, if present and unique then recreate as not unique.

```
            CommandResult cr = null;
            IndexOptionsDocument NotUnique = new IndexOptionsDocument("unique", false);
            IndexKeysDocument fileNameUploadDateIdx = new IndexKeysDocument(
                new List<BsonElement> { 
                        new BsonElement(ColumnFilename, 1), 
                        new BsonElement(ColumnUploadDate, 1) });
            var index = indexes.FirstOrDefault(
                i => i.Key.Equals(fileNameUploadDateIdx.ToBsonDocument()));

            if (index == null)
            {
                cr = files.CreateIndex(fileNameUploadDateIdx, NotUnique);
                if (!cr.Ok) {
                    //Cannot create uploadDate index
                }
            }
            else if (index.IsUnique)
            {
                cr = files.DropIndexByName(index.Name);
                if (!cr.Ok) {
                    // Cannot drop index filename_1_uploadDate_1. 
                }
                else
                {
                    cr = files.CreateIndex(fileNameUploadDateIdx, NotUnique);
                    if (!cr.Ok) {
                    //Cannot create uploadDate index
                    }
                }
            }
```

According to [Mongo docs version 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/tutorial/modify-an-index/) there's no way to modify options on an index without dropping and creating it all over again. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769603/can-i-modify-existing-index-in-mongodb-without-dropping-it) tackles this too, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24850697/2239678) provides an extension method for wrapping this drop and recreate from scratch behavior.

Comment: This can be extremely expensive on a collection with data already in it.